# Javascript lint for function existance (breaking changes in libs)

Tags: javascript, lint

I'm 'new' to Javascript and coming from staticly typed languages I'm struggling with the absence of a compiler.
Especially now I had the case when I upgraded a library which had breaking changes (renamed methods) to detect those.
I am already using a linter, but I do not get warnings when calling non existing functions of my own code.

How can I make sure that the used functions in my code are actually available?

Comment: You might be interested in [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) :)

Comment: Good question but it's...not an easy task. Ideally, you'd be using imports and exports, modules, or even TypeScript to expose functions to other files. If you're not then, it's *extremely hard* to programatically deduce whether when calling `foo()` this will exist *when the current file is executed*. You'd have to know where the current file is called, what the script order is, and scan every *other* file for exposing `foo` globally. If the current file is used in more than one place, you have to repeat this for every single place it's used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no quick and easy solution (unfortunately) but there are few things that can make the situation a lot more manageable:

- If your codebase is not too big and you have some extra time you could invest into making the wold a better place :) then you might consider converting to Typescript. For any more or less sizeable project it tends to become a big undertaking and may or may not be feasible
- Your second (and often times first) line of defense is extensive unit testing - at the very minimum, you *must* unit test ALL module interfaces to which you have a contract (such as public interfaces, exported functions etc.) A minimal "sanity check" test would make sure the module exports the functions you expect it to export, and the functions have the correct "arity" (number of the arguments). There are plenty of battle-tested unit test frameworks out there - Ava, Jasmine, Mocha/Chai to name a few
- In certain cases, ESLint can warn you of unused export methods (or missing imports). The problem is that you have to be actively looking at the lints in order to pick up the problem, which could be difficult if you are updating a third party library and it suddenly breaks your code

So to sum it up:

1. Add unit tests for all module interfaces (and more, if you have time)
2. If the project permits, explore switching to Typescript

Hope that helps!